# What is this doing: "input >> 4 & 0x0F"?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I don't understand what this code is doing at all, could someone please explain it?

```
long input;  //just here to show the type, assume it has a value stored
unsigned int output( input >> 4 & 0x0F );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

bitshifts the input 4 bits to the right, then masks by the lower 4 bits.

Take this example 16 bit number: (the dots are just for visual separation)

```
1001.1111.1101.1001 >> 4 = 0000.1001.1111.1101

0000.1001.1111.1101 & 0x0F = 1101 (or 0000.0000.0000.1101 to be more explicit)
```

Answer (score 5):

& is the bitwise AND operator. "& 0x0F" is sometimes done to pad the first 4 bits with 0s, or **ignore the first(leftmost) 4 bits** in a value.

0x0f = 00001111. So a bitwise & operation of 0x0f with any other bit pattern will retain only the rightmost 4 bits, clearing the left 4 bits.

If the input has a value of 01010001, after doing &0x0F, we'll get 00000001 - which is a pattern we get after clearing the left 4 bits.

Just as another example, this is a code I've used in a project:

Byte verflag = (Byte)(bIsAck & 0x0f) | ((version << 4) & 0xf0). Here I'm combining two values into a single Byte value to save space because it's being used in a packet header structure. bIsAck is a BOOL and version is a Byte whose value is very small. So both these values can be contained in a single Byte variable.

The first nibble in the resultant variable will contain the value of version and the second nibble will contain the value of bIsAck. I can retrieve the values into separate variables at the receiving by doing a 4 bits >> while taking the value of version.

Hope this is somewhere near to what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

That is doing a bitwise right shift the contents of "input" by 4 bits, then doing a bitwise AND of the result with 0x0F (1101).

What it does depends on the contents and type of "input". Is it an int? A long? A string (which would mean the shift and bitwise AND are being done on a pointer to the first byte).

Google for "c++ bitwise operations" for more details on what's going on under the hood.
Additionally, look at [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) because the C/C++ precedence is not exactly the same as in many other languages.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the context.  I've edited the code in the original post.